How do I prevent my header from changing when the screen gets smaller?
I've installed a Wordpress theme where the menu items of the headers go onto multiple lines when the screen size gets smaller. Only when the screen gets too small, it goes to the (mobile) hamburger menu (see image 3). Firstly it goes onto 2 lines and then 3 lines. Does someone know how to fix this issue? I only want it to stay onto 1 line or that the hamburger menu appears when it doesn't fit on 1 line.
How it is on a big screen
How it gets on a smaller screen
How it gets on a smaller screen (hamburger menu)
Thanks in advance!
Do I have to do something with the breakpoint? If yes, what exactly? I tried changing it, but it does not seem to work.

Could you show us what you tried to change and how (child theme, custom CSS …?).

I tried to change the max-width of the header. It's set on 991px. I also tried in additional css.
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
I'm not sure what I should exactly do. I managed to change it to 2 lines, but I think I'm doing it wrong.

first you have to find which css code manage the breakpoint. you can do that in reading the css code or with developer tools of your browser.

Yes, but the problem is that I can't find the breakpoint in the files. I've found: "## Bootstrap MS - 480-767 breakpoint" ... @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.col-ms-1,
.col-ms-2,
.col-ms-3,
.col-ms-4,
.col-ms-5,
.col-ms-6,
.col-ms-7,
.col-ms-8,
.col-ms-9,
.col-ms-10,
.col-ms-11 {
float: left;
}
Etc. Is this the breakpoint? If yes, how should I change it. It doesn't seem to work.

I also think it is hardcoded in the javascript, so I'm not sure if a CSS only solution will work.

I've already fixed it. I've added this in additional CSS:
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    #main-navigation {
        margin-top: 70px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
        color: #555;
    }
    .header > .navbar, .navbar.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float:none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display:none !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar.hestia_left .navbar-nav {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }
    ul#menu-primary-menu li {
        display: block;
        float:none;
    }
    ul#menu-primary-menu li a {
        color: #000;
    }
    .navbar-toggle-wrapper {
        right: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: calc(100% - 70px);
        margin-top: 70px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-transparent>.container {
        padding-top: 25px; !important;
    }
    navbar.navbar-default.navbar-transparent li:not(.btn):hover > a, 
    .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-transparent li:not(.btn):hover > a i, 
    .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-transparent .navbar-toggle:hover, 
    .navbar.navbar-default .responsive-nav-cart a:hover .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
        color: #e91e63 !important;
    }
}

